# jQuery textarea value doesn't convert line breaks

Tags: jquery, textarea, line-breaks

When adding a string, set in JavaScript, to a textarea value, it seems to convert line breaks fine. However, when grabbing this string from a data attribute, it seems to leave the line breaks as \n

These both have type of string so I am confused how one works but not the other.

How can I grab the data attribute and make the line breaks work with a textarea?

```
<div id="test" data-message="this\ntest"></div>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

```js
var html = 'this\ntest';
var div = $('#test').data('message');

$('#textarea').val(html);
$('#textarea2').val(div);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tKTLd/1/)

Comment: looks like when the value read from the attribute the `\` is escaped using `\\`, see the length diff between `html` and `div` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7q8RG/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the HTML character entity for line break within an HTML property: `&#13;`

```js
var html = 'this\ntest';
var div = $('#test').data('message');

$('#textarea').val(html);
$('#textarea2').val(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-message="this&#13;test"></div>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get it from the data attribute the`\n` is becoming escaped so you need to replace it:

```
$('#textarea2').val(div.replace("\\n","\n"));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/tKTLd/3/)

Comment: global replace: `div.replace(/\\n/g,"\n")`